# Bootstrap 4 sticky footer without fixed height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I want to use the code like it is here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/sticky-footer/

But I DO NOT want to set a fixed height. I tried just removing the height from my footer rules, but it's not staying at the bottom.

Comment: Please provide your code for other to find the solution for your issue

Comment: You would do this generally with javascript, and calculate whether the set of elements stacked above it plus the current height of the footer is greater than `window.height`, and apply a class with `position: fixed; bottom: 0;`, and remove that class if it is not. This is not particularly easy to accomplish with pure css, because css does not do backwards lookups to determine what is applied before it.

Comment: I did read the post Bootstrap 4 - Sticky footer - Dynamic footer height , the solution posted did not work for me